# Why any function in NodeJs can have req, res and next as a parameters?

Tags: node.js, api, express, request, response

```
const express=require('express')
const app=express();
const port=3000 || process.env.port;

function authenticate(req,res,next){
    console.log(' user authenticated')
    next();
}
function loadUser(req,res,next){
    console.log(' loading users ');
    next();
}

app.use('*', authenticate , loadUser);

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    
    console.log("hi user")
    res.send(" hi user ");
})


app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`server started at http://localhost:${port}`);
})
```

Can anyone explain me why any function in node js can have request , response , next as parameter.
I am new to NodeJs and have just started learning the Node middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not node, but the express 'app.use'  function that takes function of the format (req,res,next) as its parameters. Express expresses the route (as in your case '*' route ) and calls the fucntions in the defined sequence.

1. req is the parameter representing the incoming request such that u can access the incoming request object in any part of the function.
2. res is the parameter representing the outgoing response parameter such that u can use the response object anywhere in the function to send and manipulate the response to the given request.
3. next is a parameter representing the callback for the next function to be called in the route. It is an optional parameter. You need not have it unless you are going to call the upcoming function defined in the route.

Answer (score 0):

So...

First it's not 'any' function in node js...

It's only the function linked to a http route.

So take in consideration, it's a http route..

The `req` is the request variable.

The `res` is the response variable to send the response to the client.

The `next` is used in case of middleware, or if any condition make it unavailable and make it go inside another route declaration if one in intercepting the request url.

Look at your code.

If you type url `'/a404Page'` you'll be inside auth, after inside loadUser, but it will be nowhere after...

If you type url `'/'`, you'll be inside auth, after inside loadUser, and after the next will intercept the '/' route